# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS... Jest

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, jestjs, react-native-firebase

The following errors are been given when I try to run my test code

```
RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `pod install`.

 See http://invertase.link/ios for the ios setup guide.

  22 | import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
  23 | import Profile from './Profile';
> 24 | import {roomID,teamName,events} from './Home';
     |                            ^
  25 | import { ChatManager, TokenProvider } from '@pusher/chatkit-client';
  26 | import {LocalHost} from './Auth';
  27 |
```

I have tried to add the path in the podfile but keep getting the same errors. My podfile is as follows

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'
# Required by RNFirebase
target 'SCA' do


  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use 
dynamic frameworks
  #use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '~> 5.3.0'
  #pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase.podspec'

  # Pods for SCA

  target 'SCATests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'SCA-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SCA-tvOS

  target 'SCA-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I am using react-native version 0.55.4
I am also wondering would I need an apple developer account to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, you'll need to mock RNFirebase in Jest, or use a framework like Detox to do your testing. See the discussion here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1902

Comment: I have a mockFirebase but when I run pod install it fails to run on XCode